# Numpy mean and std over every terms of arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a list of 2 dimensional arrays (same shape), and would like to get the mean and deviation for all terms, in a result array of the same shape as the inputs. I have trouble understanding from the doc whether this is possible. All my attempts with axis and keepdims parameters produce results of different shapes.

I would like for example to have: mean([x, x]) equal to x, and std([x, x]) zeroes shaped like x.

Is this possible without reshaping the arrays ? If not, how to do it with reshaping ?

Example:

```
>> x= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> y= np.array([[2,3],[4,5]])
>>> np.mean([x,y])
3.0
```

I want `[[1.5,2.5],[3.5,4.5]]` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As Divikar points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173006/numpy-mean-and-std-over-every-terms-of-arrays/40173167#comment67614238_40173167), you can pass the list of arrays to `np.mean` and specify `axis=0` to average over corresponding values from each array in the list:

```
In [13]: np.mean([x,y], axis=0)
Out[13]: 
array([[ 1.5,  2.5],
       [ 3.5,  4.5]])
```

This works for lists of arbitrary length. For just two arrays, [`(x+y)/2.0` is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173006/numpy-mean-and-std-over-every-terms-of-arrays/40173167#comment67613967_40173006):

```
In [20]: %timeit (x+y)/2.0
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit np.mean([x,y], axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Or simply `np.mean([x,y],axis=0)` or `np.std([x,y],axis=0)` works too it seems.

Comment: Ah yes, because `np.asarray` is being called on its input. Thanks for the correction, @Divakar.

Comment: I was almost sure I had tried axis=0 but I guess not. Thanks ! The list are of arbitrary length indeed so I'll go with the first (and stack is not available on my numpy version  it seems).